# Assigning variables from rules from fit

Tags: fitting, syntax, core-language

It became quite clear after running this a few times that my syntax is wrong, but I can't parse out why. Anybody know of a better way to write this?

```
myFit = 
  FindFit[XData, a PDF[CauchyDistribution[CONST, b], x], {{a, 100}, {b, 100}}, x];

a = myFit[[All, 2]][[1]]
b = myFit[[All, 2]][[2]]
```

I'm fitting a cauchy distribution function to some data which gives the list of rules:

> `{a -> **, b -> **}`

But when I try to set the variables `a` and `b` to the values from the rules, it starts freaking out. Can I do this? I know about the evaluation idea of `/.`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use that to obtain variables with these values.

This gives a recursion depth exceeded message and takes up a lot of space, running away for reasons I don't quite understand.

Comment: `Fit` is a built-in function; use `fit`. It's safest to use always names starting with a lowercase letter for user-defined commands/variables/etc.

Comment: thanks I fixed that. It was called `lorentzFit` in my code but I switched it for ease of reading.  changed to `myFit`

Comment: I think you might want `FindDistributionParameters`, but without a minimal working example not much can be told. Please provide `CONST` and (at least exemplary) `XData`.

Comment: To use the rules without setting the values of the variables. `f[a,b] /. rules` To assign the values to the variables: `Clear[a, b]; {a, b} = {a, b}  /. rules` or use `Clear[a, b]; rules  /. Rule -> Set`

Comment: actually what you did is just fine (not the best approach but it works). I suppose it "freaks out" if you try to re evaluate `FindFit` after giving `a,b` values.  You can put `Clear[a,b]` before `FindFit` to take care of that.